# How to delete an active domain from a Google Apps account?

Tags: google-workspace

I'm trying to delete an active domain from a Google Apps account so that I can create a new Apps account with that domain (long story, I was using one Apps account as a stand-in while waiting for an organization to get its act together).

I keep getting an error telling me that I have e-mails or aliases still on that domain. But I've checked. I have renamed all e-mails that were created with it and deleted the aliases.  I've checked them each individually, twice. Is there any way to display e-mails by their aliases? Or something else that could be could be preventing me from deleting the domain?

Comment: You're not trying to delete the primary domain, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but user accounts [can be restored up to 5 days after deletion](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1397578).

Also, if you have deleted an account, and try to create a new one with the same user name, you will not be able to do so, for the same reason.

Maybe this 5 day grace period is what is preventing you from deleting the domain. In other words, you should be able to delete the domain five days after deleting the last user on it.

**Update**: According to [this](http://www.romneya.com/blog/consolidating-different-google-apps-domains-painful/), there is also a five days period before you can move a domain to a new Google Apps instance:

> Removing the alias from the domain or deleting the entire Google Apps
>   domain is not the solution. There is a 5-day grace period before you
>   can add the domain to another primary Google Apps domain. The solution
>   here is to call Google Support asap and set a date and time when they
>   can delete the domain and add it immediately without domain
>   validation.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what channel should be used to contact Google Support?

Comment: Yes, from within the Google Apps admin dashboard (http://www.google.com/a/`yourdomain.com`). You will need your "support PIN", which can be found on that support page. *Note*: This does not apply to legacy _free_ Google Apps instances.