# How long does Google for Work take to release an alias?

Tags: google-workspace

I want to remove an alias from a Google for Work account and create it as its own Google for Work account. How long, after I remove the alias, will Google take to release it for use in another account?

I understand that this is totally unpredictable but do we have any data of how long it took for other people to do this recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A domain alias can be released and readded to another primary domain immediately. You will need to re-verify the domain, but MX can stay the same.

Removing a primary domain takes 5 days before it can be re-added as a alias domain to some other primary domain. The 5 days can be reduced to hours if you contact the Google support and ask them to help you (purge the domain).

I have done this several times.

Comment: I moved an alias from one account to another and it did take less than 30 minutes. I confirmed this with tech support before doing it.

Comment: Glad to hear my advice was useful!

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, there's a 5-day freeze period before you can move a domain alias to another Google Apps account.

(The information used to be available [here](http://www.romneya.com/blog/consolidating-different-google-apps-domains-painful/), but the page no longer exists).

Also see this question, which is somewhat similar: [How to delete an active domain from a Google Apps account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/how-to-delete-an-active-domain-from-a-google-apps-account)